# Maximum number of acceptable child classes

Tags: php, laravel, oop

Using PHP Mess Detector https://phpmd.org I found a rule that tells me to refactor a class with more than 15 childrens.

*My class in this question is a base class for repositories that implements various methods that each repository must have.*

My question is the following.

I always believed that the greatest advantage of inheritance in object-oriented programming was to avoid code repetition, so how could be a problem if a class being used by many childrens?

The rule is the following:

```xml
<rule name="NumberOfChildren"
      since="0.2"
      message = "The {0} {1} has {2} children. Consider to rebalance this class hierarchy to keep number of children under {3}."
      class="PHPMD\Rule\Design\NumberOfChildren"
      externalInfoUrl="https://phpmd.org/rules/design.html#numberofchildren">
    <description>
    </description>
    <priority>2</priority>
    <properties>
        <property name="minimum" value="15" description="Maximum number of acceptable child classes." />
    </properties>
    <example />
</rule>
```

I appreciate any help to clarify this doubt.

Comment: I never use `extends`, I don't use traits nor God forbid abstract classes. I have tons of interfaces and implementations, each clear and focused, easy to maintain and test. PHPMD has nothing to complain when inspecting my codebase. So it's doable… it's your design & decisions that are bad.

Comment: But aint it smart to have a abstract repository class, so you for example can implement a generic findOrFail method utilising the fail method for example? or implement a generic delete method.

Comment: It's a shortcut, it's not smart, I don't use shortcuts. Delete/find methods are available inside Doctrine repositories which I inject into my repositories.

Comment: Example repository: https://gist.github.com/mikemix/c0092208216e4f07dd0f0c6e4978fbe7. I have tens of such repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience working with sniffer tools, it is more a smell than an error. I feel like the design choice you made is totally the correct way and a Trait or any other solution is more of a hack.

So take everything it tells you into consideration, analyze it and if you still feel it is the correct way, keep it.

The smell can be if you make something to general is extended, it can be used i to many different domains. So that can be something you should design your way out of.

Comment: don't agree with this, altough of course it always depends on your software

Comment: In many cases this could be a problem, but i feel this is the same as saying the Model is extended to much or the BaseController class is extended to heavily. No they are not. They are needed for the framework to work. My experience also says that you often end up making more specific repositories in time.

Comment: @anjalis what in the case of BaseController should we also convert that into a trait, then we loose the polymorphism of classes?

Comment: i am not saying that it should be converted to trait, if you check my answer that explains why i don't agree with your answer

Comment: But then you loose polymorphism? What if he requires to pass an unknown repostiry to a class, it is a good design to have an abstract class to define as a parameter.

Comment: I am not saying that you should not use polymorphism at all, just use it wisely and such deep hierarchy looks like it was not used wisely look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: I agree, but not in the case of an repository. It is such a generic way of doing it, Symfony even has a baseRepository you can inherit from https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php so you would load that with composition? that is gonna be a mess in the codebase, have to implement a lot of generic boiler plate proxy methods just to call the compositioned repository.

Comment: Even with the considerations against this answer I believe that it is still the most suitable to answer my doubt. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score -2):

Use trait instead of class. Trait has no limit
like :

```
trait ParentTrait {...}
```

So, you can use this in all class like

```
  class child {
     use ParentTrait;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Using a trait will solve the problem. But could you explain the reason for the restriction of child classes?

Comment: Traits usually are used for smaller tasks and modifications - adding behaviour they are good tool but i would not use it for such big class hierarchies

Comment: I feel trait should not be used in this context. Traits is when you have something general you want in multiple classes. A good example if you want models to send email. Make a SendEmail trait and use it where it should be used.

Comment: So, what is your suggestion about his problem?

Comment: I have answered the question, but that seems not acceptable to say that extending a Repository is a fair design decision. I do not feel he is in the wrong on this one.

Comment: extending Repositories, i would not do that, when you do that you probably don't have good domain model and class hierarchy extending Repository objects 15  levels deep smells quite with a big mess, but without code it's hard to say

Answer (score -3):

Problems can arise also with inheritance a lot of inheritance causes a lot of dependencies on underlying code, imagine you have two classess which are subclasses of parent class, you add functionality in parent class but you make a mistake and you will brake all of your classes and chances that happens rises with growing hierarchy. Usually frameworks solve it by composition/aggregation and dependency injection.